# unable to mount and read gpt/ufs drive in my ubuntu server 12.04lts

Tags: ubuntu

I have a 1tb drive that was part of a freenas server mounted as ufs, it is full of data. My freenas system crashed, so decided to build an ubuntu 12.04 server, but I am unable to mount the drive, getting an error when I fdisk saying that my gpt drive cannot be mounted. Could someone please give me some ideas of how I can mount this drive, I really don't want to lose all the data.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the module *ufs* mounted:

```
  sudo rmmod ufs
  sudo modprobe ufs
```

Now make a mount point for your disk:

```
 mkdir ~/ufsmtpt
```

and now mount the disk as follows:

```
  sudo mount -r -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb1 /home/yourname/ufsmtpt
```

where I assumed that you wish to mount the first partition of disk */dev/sdb*, change it as suitable.

Keep in mind that the [mount man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) states, concerning *ufs*:

> UFS is a filesystem widely used in different operating systems. The problem are differences among implementations. Features of some implementations are undocumented, so its hard to recognize the type of ufs automatically. That's why the user must specify the type of ufs by mount option. Possible values are: ....

So if you find any further difficulty, do not get discouraged, and read the man page above for further assistance.